# map to a custom route triggers also loading of static files through that route

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I want that my index.cshtml is only returned when the following route is active:

http://www.example.com/2/345044

The below code works, but when the code for returning the razor file via:

return View(Index); then the Index action is hit again multiple times

with values from the script/image/stylesheet tags like:

tag has value 'css' and metaversion has value 'site.css'

thats the url in the Layout.cshtml:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
```

How can I prevent that the Index action is triggered  with those file requests?

Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{ 
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute("history", "{tag}/{metaversion}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
     });
}
```

Comment: You haven't enabled static files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static files are not enabled by default.  You must turn on the features you wish to use:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```